How to Set Custom Namespace Prefix for SOAP Fault Element in Spring Web Services?
I am working on a Spring Web Services project where I need to customize the SOAP fault response. Specifically, I want to ensure that the Fault element in the SOAP response uses a custom namespace prefix, s, rather than the default one.
Here is my current handleFault implementation:
@Override
public boolean handleFault(MessageContext messageContext, Object endpoint) throws Exception {
    SaajSoapMessage soapResponse = (SaajSoapMessage) messageContext.getResponse();
    SOAPEnvelope envelope = soapResponse.getSaajMessage().getSOAPPart().getEnvelope();
    SOAPBody body = envelope.getBody();
    SOAPHeader header = soapResponse.getSaajMessage().getSOAPHeader();

    // Remove the default "SOAP-ENV" namespace and replace it with "s"
    envelope.removeNamespaceDeclaration("SOAP-ENV");
    envelope.addNamespaceDeclaration("s", "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/");
    
    // Set the prefix "s" for the envelope, body, and header
    envelope.setPrefix("s");
    body.setPrefix("s");
    if (header != null) {
        header.setPrefix("s");
    }

    // Create a new SOAPFault or modify the existing one
    SOAPFault fault = body.getFault() != null ? body.getFault() : body.addFault();

    fault.setPrefix("s");
    fault.setFaultCode(new QName("http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/", "Client", "s"));
    fault.setFaultString("403 Forbidden: Access forbidden. Please check your permissions.");

    // Save the changes to ensure everything is serialized properly
    soapResponse.getSaajMessage().saveChanges();

    return true;
}

This code produces the following SOAP response:
<s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
   <s:Header/>
   <s:Body>
      <Fault xmlns="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
         <faultcode xmlns="">s:Client</faultcode>
         <faultstring xml:lang="en" xmlns="">403 Forbidden: message[403 Forbidden from PUT http://127.0.0.1:8081/vms/display/screenwalls/scrwall_test_error403/mapping] responseBody[{"status":"ERROR","payload":"VMS Error Payload 403 (scrwall_test_error403)  (scrwall_test_error403)"}]</faultstring>
      </Fault>
   </s:Body>
</s:Envelope>

As you can see, the Fault element is missing the s prefix despite calling fault.setPrefix("s")
Instead of , I would like it to be <s:Fault> like this:
<s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
   <s:Header/>
   <s:Body>
      <s:Fault>
         <faultcode>s:Client</faultcode>
         <faultstring xml:lang="en">403 Forbidden: message[403 Forbidden]</faultstring>
      </s:Fault>
   </s:Body>
</s:Envelope>

How can I ensure that the Fault element in the SOAP body uses the s prefix?

I found the problem. Faulthandler codes was correct indeed. It was @Override public void afterCompletion(...) method overwriting prefixes with
  node.setPrefix("");

I made this change and it is working
  // Check if the element is a Fault, and skip modifying the prefix
                if (!"Fault".equals(node.getLocalName())) {
                    node.setPrefix("");

